# Decimation works more in certain areas of mesh that others

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have recently started using decimation for a project quite frequently and suddenly the results I am getting are strange at best.

It is almost as if the decimation is relying on weight for its decimation.

1. Desired effect

[image: Desired effect]

2. Start with simple subdivides to maintain the squares

[image: Start with simple subdivides to maintain the squares]

3. Decimate to around 3k verts (0.05 factor in this case)

[image: Decimate to around 3k verts (0.05 factor in this case)]

4. Results
   [image: Results]

You can see that there is a weird bias when decimating, sometimes full squares are left intact and parts are so decimated they're just solid orange.

This also happens even if I reset my Blender and reimport the blank model repeating all the steps.